# JavaScript 'IN' Statement

Tags: javascript, arrays

I just started learning `JavaScript` and am currently making a Tic Tac Toe Game.
The problem is that the `IN` statement, always returns `True` on the condition that I mentioned.

```
function getMove(index){
    key=parseInt(index);
    var temp;
    temp=moves;
    elem=document.getElementById(index);
    var valid_move=(key in temp);
    document.getElementById('warning').innerText=valid_move;`
```

The 5th statement in the Function above:- `var valid_move=(key in temp);`

It always Returns `True`, though I change the value of `index` as soon as it is occupied:-

```
var key;
var elem;
var moves=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var score_x=0;
var score_o=0;

var X=true;
function getMove(index){
    key=parseInt(index);
    var temp;
    temp=moves;
    elem=document.getElementById(index);
    var valid_move=(key in temp);
    document.getElementById('warning').innerText=valid_move;

    if (X && valid_move){
        elem.innerText='X';
        elem.style.color='Crimson';
        moves[key-1]='occ';
        X=false;
        document.getElementById('head').innerText=temp;
    }else if(!X && valid_move){
        elem.innerText='O';
        elem.style.color='blue';
        moves[key-1]='occ';
        document.getElementById('head').innerText=temp;
        X=true;        
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('warning').innerText='Already Occupied !'
    }
    var len;
    len=temp.length;
    if (len==1){
        document.write('GAME OVER');
    }
}
```

This is the whole code.

As u can see, as soon as the index is occupied, I change it's value to `occ`, so that a player cannot place a move at the same position Twice (as it is in `TICTACTOE`).

But inspite of that, I am able to place a move at the same position twice.

Please Help.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what `in` does https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: That said it's really not clear what `var valid_move=(key in temp);` is supposed to do?

Comment: Sir , I just used IN to check whether the specified Valu exists in the array 'moves' or not .

Comment: @smat-8097 that's where you're wrong: `in` checks if the key exists, not the value. Read the doc.

Comment: Okay , I got it Now. Is there something I can do to search for the Value .(except for using for loop ).

Comment: Why has the question been put to Hold ? 2 People have already answered my Question accurately, and my Code is fully functional Now .

Answer (score 1):

Changing the value of a key doesn't remove the key. You only ever check if the key exists, and, yes, it does. You never remove it. You are changing the value, so what you need to check is the value of the key:

```
var valid_move = key in temp && temp[key] != 'occ';
```

This checks if the key exists **and** if it's value is not `'occ'`.

**key and value**

Your array has **keys** and **values**. Every key in the array **holds a value**. The word "key" is not a reserved word, but it still is a technical term used in the language specs. Your confusion seems to come from not making a difference between the **key** itself and the value the key is holding. You could say that the key itself **is** a value, but the **value it holds** is a separate value.

Take this: `someArray[0] = 1;` Here `0` is the key and 1 is the value. They key **is** `0`, but the value it holds is `1`. The key itself will not change to `1`, it will remain `0`. It **is** `0`. The value it holds changes to `1`.

So when you do `moves[key]='occ';` you don't change the key, you change the value that the key holds.

When you initialize your array you provide it with **values** not with **keys**, the keys are automatically generated and are 0-based indices. So this line:

```
var moves = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

is equivalent to this:

```
var moves = {0:1, 1:2, 2:3, 3:4, 4:5, 5:6, 6:7, 7:8, 8:9, 9:10};
```

because you initialize the **keys** `0` to `9` with the **values** `1` to `10`.

When we talk about "value of a key", we do not mean the key itself, we mean the value that this key holds. This is true for any language, not just Javascript.

Comment: Sir , I think i Made the mistake of not considering 'key' as a reserved word. Is that Right ?. I just created a variable key and assigned to it the value which i get as an argument.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a more detailled explanation as to what **keys** and their **values** actually are. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir . It really helped !

Comment: Sir , Can't thank u enough . I have successfully created my Game .

Answer (score 0):

You do not make the difference between the key and the value, because your data format is quite confusing: the values are quite close to the keys.

The `in` operator checks if the **key** exists inside the object.

Here, you work on an array: `var moves=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];`

So inside `moves`, there is the value 1 inside `moves[0]`/the key 0, until 10 inside `moves[9]`/the key 9.
Let's say you set `moves[9] = 'occ'`: the index 9 still exists, so when you do `9 in moves`, it returns `true`, of course.

If you want to use `in`, do `delete moves[key-1];` to remove the assignment instead of `moves[key-1] = 'occ';`.

Check the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: Sir , I did exactly what u are saying at the first Go . But using delete was leaving holes in the array making it difficult ti use the array. That's why i changed the value of the index so that when the IN statement searches for the value , it returns false since the value of the index has now become 'occ'.

Comment: I think the format of your data is basically wrong. Deleting the data from the array only allows you to use `in`, but yet, the way you design your data storage is quite weird.

Comment: Well Sir , can you provide a possible solution for the same . And as you say , I know it is quiet weird , As I started Learning JS just a week ago from w3 Schools.